# read csv file in android

Tags: java, android, csv, read.csv

I want to read a csv file from a specific path , but the code does not show me the contents of the file without receiving an error (if when I add the csv file to the program source and the asset folder,The contents of the file are displayed in textview without any problem)

**This is my code:**

```
try{File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/dl");
    File cert = new File(dir,"m.csv");
    
    InputStream sl = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(cert));

    

BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(sl,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));


String line="";



while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        String[] token;
        token=line.split(",");
        

for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++){
        dt.sets2(token[i]+"-");
        s=dt.gets1();
        if(token[i].length()>15){
            s=dt.gets2()+"---";
        }
        
        }
        tv.setText(s+"token lrn"+Integer.toString(token.length));
        
        weathersam.add(dt);
    
        }
        
        
        
        
        }catch(Exception e){
            error=e.getMessage();
            Log.d("iii", e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: You got an error?

Comment: I have updated the code (please check the code) but I am not getting any error and also the try catch exception return  null, can you test it? please

Comment: I see no Download folder. I see no try-catch. I see no null. And in your post you tell us that you got an error.

Comment: I had forgotten that the compilation issue was fixed by changing the code, now I've edited the whole question, I apologize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** ,I added below code to the **manifest** and the problem was solved

```
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    
 .

 </application>
```

Comment: "Caution: After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level 30), the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be ready to support scoped storage and to migrate app data for users on those devices.": https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-in-production-app